# simple html dom extract links without domain name

Tags: php, web-scraping

how can i get the links without the hdo.to name? using simple html dom. extract links without domain name

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://hdo.to/';

$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a[href^="https://hdo.to/country/"]') as $klk) {
 echo $links[] = $klk;
}

?>

This is what i am getting 
<a href="https://hdo.to/country/asia">Asia</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/china">China</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/euro">Euro</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/france">France</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/hongkong">HongKong</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/India">India</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/international">International</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/japan">Japan</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/korea">Korea</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/taiwan">Taiwan</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/thailand">Thailand</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a><a href="https://hdo.to/country/united-states">United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a><a href=https://hdo.to/country/united-kingdom title=United kingdom>United Kingdom</a>
```

i Watnt to get the links like this /country/china without the domain name

Comment: Use your xpath to posivily match the HREF first, then later as a secondary process, strip off the prefixing part you don't want. Your xpath is selecting anchor tags, getting the right anchor tag is the job of the attribute rule you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://hdo.to/';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$links = array();

foreach($html->find('a[href^="https://hdo.to/country/"]') as $klk) {
  $link = $klk->href;
  $link_parts = parse_url( $link );
  $links[] = $link_parts['path'];
}

print_r( $links );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /country/asia
    [1] => /country/china
    [2] => /country/euro
    [3] => /country/france
    [4] => /country/hongkong
    [5] => /country/India
    [6] => /country/international
    [7] => /country/japan
    [8] => /country/korea
    [9] => /country/taiwan
    [10] => /country/thailand
    [11] => /country/united-kingdom
    [12] => /country/united-states
    [13] => /country/united-states
    [14] => /country/united-states
    [15] => /country/united-states
    [16] => /country/united-states
    [17] => /country/united-states
    [18] => /country/united-kingdom
)
```

**EDIT:**

If you only want to remove domain name from your output:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://hdo.to/';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$links = array();

foreach($html->find('a[href^="https://hdo.to/country/"]') as $klk) {
 echo $links[] = str_replace( 'https://hdo.to', '', $klk );
}
```

Result:

```
<a href="/country/asia">Asia</a>
<a href="/country/china">China</a>
<a href="/country/euro">Euro</a>
<a href="/country/france">France</a>
<a href="/country/hongkong">HongKong</a>
<a href="/country/India">India</a>
<a href="/country/international">International</a>
<a href="/country/japan">Japan</a>
<a href="/country/korea">Korea</a>
<a href="/country/taiwan">Taiwan</a>
<a href="/country/thailand">Thailand</a>
<a href="/country/united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a>
<a href="/country/united-states">United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-states title=United states>United States</a>
<a href=/country/united-kingdom title=United kingdom>United Kingdom</a>
```

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: now im just getting the plain text, i Want to get this <a href="https://hdo.to/country/asia">Asia</a> like i show you in my example, but i want it without the somain. That  is all want.

Comment: Have you tried my code? I have tested my code it is giving your desired result.

Comment: Please review the answer again

Comment: i am new to this how i do that ?

Comment: Click 'right' sign on left side of the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141652

Comment: last thing if i have https://hdo.to/country/asia and https://hdo.to/year/200 How can i replace  https://hdo.to/country/asia for  https://hdo.to/paiz/asia, And https://hdo.to/year/200 for https://hdo.to/ano/200 ?

Comment: You can do it by using str_replace() function as used above in second example. Please read str_replace() function in detail from php documentation.